# How to output the TAGs of an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have an EC2 Instance like below;

```
"Ec2Instance": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
    "Properties": {
        "ImageId": { "Ref" : "RegionalAmi" },
        "AvailabilityZone": {
            "Ref": "Ec2AZ"
        },
        "InstanceType": { "Ref" : "AWSInstanceType" },
        "KeyName": { "Ref" : "publicKey" },
        "NetworkInterfaces": [
            {
                "NetworkInterfaceId": {
                    "Ref": "Nic0"
                },
                "DeviceIndex": "0"
            },
            {
                "NetworkInterfaceId": {
                    "Ref": "Nic1"
                },
                "DeviceIndex": "1"
            }
        ],
        "Tags" : [
            {   
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": "Sample-TOPOLOGY"
            },
            {   
                "Key": "Resources",
                "Value": "r0"
            }
        ],
        
    },
    "DependsOn": [
        "Nic0",
        "Nic1"
    ]
},
```

I want in output section to print the tags used for this EC2 instance. I see that following way, we can retrieve some of the properties of EC2 instance.

```
"Ec2InstanceName": {
    "Description": "Public name of EC2",
    "Value" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "vSRXInstance", "PublicDnsName" ] }
},
```

But not Tags. If I use following, i get some error like "Template error: resource Ec2Instance does not support attribute type Tags in Fn::GetAtt"

```
"Ec2InstanceTag": {
    "Description": "Tags of vSRX",
    "Value" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "vSRXInstance", "Tags" ] }
},
```

Any help appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. Outputting tags is not supported. You would have to develop your own [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) to get the tags and return them.

Otherwise, you have to hardcode them in `Outputs` or use as `Parameters` which you can then reference in the `Outputs`.